# weather.yahooapis.com returns "Connection Refused"

Tags: yahoo-weather-api

My weather app using the yahoo API worked fine for the last year using OAuth protocol. It suddenly stopped working working yesterday throwing this:

> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (502)
>   Bad Gateway.

[weather.yahooapis.com](http://weather.yahooapis.com) also returns

> Connection refused Description: Connection refused

Any idea on what the problem could be; if its on my end or an issue with yahoo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is probably on the Yahoo end.

My application broke too. I have temporarily fixed the problem by replacing **weather.yahooapis.com** to **weather-ydn-yql.media.yahoo.com**. The endpoint URL which was exposed previously is down today, I found alternative working URL through some google searches (apparently it seems they have updated their android mobile app yesterday which may have broken this, don't know guessing this based on google search results).

Anyhow, Yahoo weather developer document now recommends not to use **weather.yahooapis.com** and use instead YQL

You can use below URL for as per YQL recommendation instead of

**Old URL**

http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=2502265

**New recommended URL**

https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%3D2502265

Here, parameter w is WOEID.

Comment: It is comforting to know that the problem is just not for me. Using query.yahooapis.com works, I just have to replace the /rss/channel/item/ node with /query/results/channel/item/ so not that painful of a workaround.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Great to know that it worked for you too. Yahoo is not anymore the same company it used to be, I need to look for more reliable weather API.

Comment: This api endpoint has been deprecated now, yahoo has taken it down